# Server Mute Music Bot? .setDeaf is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

Well so I am trying to server mute my bot when it joins a VC but all I get is

`TypeError: bot.setDeaf is not a function`

I've tried the same with

`let bot = message.guild.members.cache.get('ID');`

But that didn't work either.
What am I doing wrong? I couldn't really find anything anywhere that would help me.
Here's the rest. Thanks in advance!

```js
let bot = client.users.cache.get('ID');
bot.setDeaf(true);
```

Comment: Looks like you should use `setSelfDeaf` instead
[discord.js.org/docs/setSelfDeaf](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSelfDeaf)

Comment: Yeah I know that one but I saw other bots server muting themselves and I was just wondering how they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note 1.** You can only call `.setDeaf()` from a VoiceState. Even though you can only have one VoiceState per user, the VoiceState is scoped to the instantiating `GuildMember` instance.

**Note 2.** You can access the VoiceState property via `GuildMember.voice`, and then call the relevant methods.

**Note 3.** Contrary to what others suggested, there is a fine difference between `.setDeaf()` and `.setSelfDeaf()`. Firstly, `.setDeaf()` **server-deafens** the member of that voice state. That means there will be a nice red icon next to that member's voice presence. [image: Server Deafen]. An entry to the audit log will also pop up, and you can specify the reason in `.setDeaf()`.

On the other hand, `.setSelfDeaf()` can only be called on the bot's VoiceState. The library internally checks if the VoiceState user ID matches the client user ID. (see https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/structures/VoiceState.js#L192)
Self-deafening will not generate an audit log entry, and the icon next to the bot will be gray, not red.

So your code would be as follows:

```js
//exit if the voice state property does not exist
if(!message.guild.me.voice) return message.channel.send("I'm not in a voice channel...");

//deafen
message.guild.me.voice.setDeaf(true, "Yeah...this is a deafening test.").then(() => {
message.channel.send("I have successfully server deafened myself.");
});
```

You can view the documentation for `.setDeaf()` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setDeaf)

Comment: Wow thank you so much totally what I was looking for, I didn't really know how to tell the bot to server mute itself, because that's what I tried in my code above. Oh and it worked too, thanks again!